# no text appears whenever i type using nokia lumia phone

Tags: keyboard

I have not been using watsapp much for days since after i have updated the app, i cannot see my typed messages unless i send. The part where the letters and other icons that's supposed to be showing is covered by a gray screen and only suggested words appear. So whenever i reply and write messages, i do them "blindly" and delete everything and repeat typing if i make any mistake. I tried deleting and re installing the app 3 times but same happens.

other apps are working fine and i can see my typed words. This app the only causing some problems.

pls help. Thank you.

Comment: please mention the app version number.